# Using jquery pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins, jquery-pagination

I want to use [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination), but I don't know if it'll meet all of my requirements.

I know I have to use JSON to fetch the data from the server and  then use it at the client side, is that right?. For now, that's fine, because I only have very few records, but when I have thousands of ; will it be convenient to bring all the data at once? What I would like to know is :

- Is there any way to query the
  database every time I press the
  number of an specific page? I ask
  this cause I don't think is a good
  idea to load all the data in one go,
  is it?
- I used to pass the id of the record I
  was going to edit like this

:

```
 <td align="center">
       <c:url value="edititem.htm" var="url">
              <c:param name="id" value="${item.id}"/>
       </c:url>
       <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/>"><img src="images/edit.png" width="14" height="14" alt="edit"/></a>
  </td>
```

but now I don't know not how to do it.

I really hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

... I'll give it a shot. How about this? If you look at the source of the demo page, there's a member.js file and I think that's the mock data for the demo. I has a one variable 'members' that's used by the plugin. So you're right, an ajax call would be how you need to get your data from the server. Personally I think that's a bummer since it's all hard coded :-(

From the documentation:

> **CALLBACK**
>       A callback function that is called when a user clicks on a pagination link. The function receives two parameters: the new page index and the pagination container (a DOM element). If the callback returns false, the event propagation is stopped. Default value: function(){return false;}. This callback function is essential for the functionality of the pagination! It should contain code that updates your content. For a fast user experience you should NOT load content via AJAX in this function. Instead, pre-load some content pages and switch between them with this function.

... 2 sentences are a problem though:

> For a fast user experience you should NOT load content via AJAX in this function. Instead, pre-load some content pages and switch between them with this function.

... pre loading content might be a non starter in some situations, defeating the purpose of using pagination :-( So you wold be on your own rolling the callback function to get the data sets.

Did you try contacting the author about server side interaction samples?